# How to reset Telerik Kendo ComboBox filter inside of a Kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-combobox

I have a Kendo Grid with a ComboBox in it that is set with a "contains" filter. When the user enters garbage (aka a value NOT in the list), I want to reset the filter and re-select the last valid value.

I use Razor syntax to create the grid, and the ComboBox in question is a composite object using this template:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(m => m)
        .Name("CurrentSalesRep")
        .Filter("contains")
        .DataValueField("Code")
        .DataTextField("Name")
        .BindTo((System.Collections.IList)ViewData["SalesReps"])
)
```

In an attempt to set up certain universal events for all comboboxes in my site, I run a client-side JQuery routine that sets up the "focus", "blur" and "change" events bases on a JQuery selector that finds the textbox that Kendo renders.

On focus, I store the previous value, then on blur and change, I want to determine whether the input value is valid and then re-select the previous value:

```
function setupKendoComboBoxEvents(comboBox, parentContainer) {
    var cntrlId = comboBox.attr("Id");
    var $ctrl = comboBox;
    var $cbx = $ctrl.data("kendoComboBox");

    var input = $cbx.input;

    input.on("focus", function () {
        if ($cbx.select() !== -1) {
            $("#" + cntrlId).attr("data-prev-value", $cbx.select());
        }
        $cbx.value("");
        $cbx.open();
    });

    input.on("change", function (e) {
        if ($cbx.select() === -1) {
            $cbx.dataSource.filter([]);
            $cbx.select(parseInt($("#" + cntrlId).attr("data-prev-value")));
        }
    });

    input.on("blur", function (e) {
        if ($cbx.select() === -1) {
            $cbx.dataSource.filter([]);
            $cbx.select(parseInt($("#" + cntrlId).attr("data-prev-value")));
        }
    });
}
```

Now, the problem. This works great for stand-alone Kendo ComboBoxes. However, when I run this routine onGridEdit for a ComboBox inside a Kendo Grid, the filter appears to "reset" itself and re-selects the main desired value. The value that is submitted for the row retains the "garbage" value and MVC is unable to re-constitute the "CurrentSalesRep" object, resulting in an invalid ModelState.

Is there something special about the combination of a Kendo Grid and Kendo ComboBox? How can I guarantee a valid selection in the grid form post?

Comment: Does your combobox default to a valid value, or when it loads do you display an empty "Please select" item? If you do display a "Please select" then is this defined as garbage?

Comment: No placeholder value on these. The "garbage" value is the user-entered filter criteria, which after the blur event is no longer visible to the user. They see the reset, but the Kendo model that is used to submit the post keeps the "garbage".

This only occurs for a ComboBox in a Kendo grid, not outside of it.